# Get Response Headers from Angular HttpClient call Async method azure AI computer vision

Tags: angular, azure, async-await, computer-vision, azure-ai

I am trying to implement [Azure Computer Vision Recognize text AI](https://westcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5adf991815e1060e6355ad44/operations/587f2c6a154055056008f200) using Angular. I need to find a particular header from the response of the first Http call and then call the second one. But I am unable to find the header. Can you please help me find what I am missing here? You can see the things I had already tried in the code below.

```
async post(url: string): Promise<any> {
    const body = {
      url: url,
      observe: 'response'
    };
    const options = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': config.api.apiKey,
        'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'allow',
        'resolveWithFullResponse': 'true',
        'responseType': 'text'
      })
    };
    const result = await this.http.post(config.api.baseUrl, body, options)
      .subscribe(async (res: Response) => {
        console.log(res);
        const operationLocation = res.headers.get('Operation-Location');
        return await this.http.get(operationLocation, options).toPromise();
      });
    return result;
  }
```

I am able to see the response headers in the browser network, but the `res` object is always null.

[image]

The Azure documentation says "The service has accepted the request and will start processing later. 
It will return Accepted immediately and include an “*Operation-Location” header. Client side should further query the operation status using the URL specified in this header. The operation ID will expire in 48 hours.*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to fix the problem. Luckily I came to read [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts/javascript-hand-text) where it is been mentioned that "Recognize Text method does not return any information in the body of a successful response". And later I was able to finish my requirement using the `OCR` [API](https://westcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5adf991815e1060e6355ad44/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499e1fc). I had to change my base URL to the one below.

`https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v2.0/ocr`

**home.component.ts**

```
async submit() {
    if (this.url.value) {
        const result: any = await this.detectionService.post(this.url.value);
        const resultArray: Array < string > = [];
        this.lines = result.regions[0].lines.forEach((obj: any) => {
            obj.words.forEach((word: any) => {
                resultArray.push(word.text);
            });
        });
        this.stringResult = resultArray.join(' ');
    }
}
```

**service.ts**

```
async post(url: string): Promise<any> {
    const body = {
      url: url
    };
    const options = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': config.api.apiKey
      })
    };
    return await this.http.post(config.api.baseUrl, body, options).toPromise();
  }
```

I was able to get the desired output as below.

```
{"language":"en","textAngle":0,"orientation":"Up","regions":[{"boundingBox":"74,172,995,446","lines":[{"boundingBox":"159,172,884,76","words":[{"boundingBox":"159,177,47,58","text":"If"},{"boundingBox":"221,194,129,54","text":"you"},{"boundingBox":"369,183,180,53","text":"want"},{"boundingBox":"566,183,73,53","text":"to"},{"boundingBox":"657,172,185,64","text":"shine"},{"boundingBox":"864,176,124,60","text":"like"},{"boundingBox":"1008,194,35,42","text":"a"}]},{"boundingBox":"74,261,995,76","words":[{"boundingBox":"74,279,243,52","text":".—sun,"},{"boundingBox":"335,261,145,60","text":"first"},{"boundingBox":"501,261,158,68","text":"burn"},{"boundingBox":"683,261,124,60","text":"like"},{"boundingBox":"827,279,35,42","text":"a"},{"boundingBox":"882,279,187,58","text":"sun.."}]},{"boundingBox":"381,347,436,43","words":[{"boundingBox":"381,347,51,43","text":"X:"},{"boundingBox":"440,348,222,42","text":"P.TAbdul"},{"boundingBox":"680,352,137,38","text":"Kalam"}]},{"boundingBox":"541,589,158,29","words":[{"boundingBox":"541,589,17,22","text":"B"},{"boundingBox":"560,589,139,29","text":"rainyQ!0te'"}]}]}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Using [HttpResponse](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post) as the expected response type, which would give you full response. So that you can access headers from it.

```
const result = await this.http.post<HttpResponse<Object>>(config.api.baseUrl, body, options)
      .subscribe(async (res: Response) => {
        console.log(res);
        const operationLocation = res.headers.get('Operation-Location');
        return await this.http.get(operationLocation, options).toPromise();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried it. But the response itself is null.

Comment: You mean after trying this, your response is null? Or you are not getting response at all?

Comment: I have aupdated my question, please check. Thanks in advance.